# Push value to array onclick and loop to add array values. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

So i am pretty new at this and want to be able to add a dollar to the "deposit" text box every time I click the button. I'm going to have to do this with a quarter, dime, and nickel, button as well. This is what I have so far.

```
<input type="button" value="Dollar" id="dollar" />
$<input type="text" id="deposit" />
```

And the javascript is:

```
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

var item = [];

var total = 0;
for (i=0; i < item.length; i++){
total += item[i];
$("deposit").value = total;
}
$("dollar").onclick = item.push(1);
```

Whatever help you can give is much appreciated!

Comment: `.onclick = xxx` should be a function so `function() {item.push(1)}` or if you want to be fancy `item.push.bind(item, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/UZUzJ/)

```
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
var add = function(fld,val) {
  return (parseFloat(fld.value)+val).toFixed(2);
}

window.onload=function() {
  $("dollar").onclick=function() { 
    $("deposit").value = add($("deposit"),1);
  }  
  $("dime").onclick=function() { 
    $("deposit").value = add($("deposit"),.1);
  } 
  $("nickel").onclick=function() { 
    $("deposit").value = add($("deposit"),.05);
  } 
  $("refund").onclick = function() {    
    $("deposit").value = "0.00";
  } 
}
```

Comment: This works great! Then if I wanted to refund the money I could just do    <input type="button" value="Refund" id="refund" /> and 
$("refund").onclick = function() {
$("deposit").value = " "; }
right?

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a NaN when I run it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.9.1" data-semver="1.9.1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Dollar" id="dollar" />
$   <input type="text" id="deposit" />
  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

  var item = [];

  $("#dollar").click(function() {
    item.push(1);
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      total += item[i];
      $("#deposit").val(total);
    }
  });

});
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hZmaZ1I3k3ACbq2YX79j?p=preview)

Comment: No one asked for jQuery

Comment: But @ImperialCereal use in his code $("deposit") so it suggested me that he uses jQuery.

Comment: No, he created his own $ function - jQuery would be $("#deposit")

Comment: Is creating the $ function the best way to call html elements or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I think that a good idea is to use jQuery. It makes life easier a JavaScript programmer :) As you have any questions we will be glad to answer.

Comment: I love jquery, however in this example it is clearly overkill as you can see from my answer. Not much to save with jquery since the calculation is pure JS